# 7zip container format

Tags: compression, 7zip

I know how to compress an individual file using LZMA but it's not clear how to generate a valid 7-zip container for a collection of files. [How do I write binary data for 7z archive format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496204/how-do-i-write-binary-data-for-7z-archive-format) explains how to create an empty container, but it's not clear what should get written for each file entry. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [7-ZIP SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html). It contains sourcecode for C, C++, C# and Java wich should answer your question.